# Using a Maven pom.xml file to contain a single, compatible version of a class of ConfigurableApplicationContext

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I have a project that uses a Maven build configuration in IntelliJ.
I keep getting the following error:

The method's class, org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext, is available from the following locations:

```
jar:file:/C:/Users/tlmitch/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/5.2.8.RELEASE/spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/org/springframework/context/ConfigurableApplicationContext.class

The class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:

org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext: file:/C:/Users/tlmitch/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/5.2.8.RELEASE/spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext
```

If I do a cntrl-shift-n and look for the class ConfigurableApplicationContext - it does come back with a list of 8 instances where the class exists.

From what digging I've done, it seems I should be looking at my pom.xml file for an artifactId of spring-context, and then putting in exclusion blocks that excludes all but one of the references.

Problem is, I can't find artifactIds in the pom.xml file that seem to correspond to the duplicate references.  And if I just start excluding stuff at random I get into a lot more trouble than I start with.

[Here is a shot of the multiple instances of the class:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88n1Q.png)

And I've attached the pom.xml file.

If anyone could just point me in the right direction.  Thanks so much; been having trouble making headway with this.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>gov.sandia.sfiapp</groupId>
    <artifactId>SFIApplication</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>SFIApplication</name>

  <properties>
    <appNameShort>SFIApplication</appNameShort>
    <build.number>${maven.build.timestamp}</build.number>
    <java.version>11.0</java.version>
    <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
    <clm.serverUrl>https://do.sandia.gov/seis-repo/iq </clm.serverUrl>
    <clm.applicationId>${project.artifactId}</clm.applicationId>
    <clm.additionalScopes>provided, system</clm.additionalScopes>
    <clm.stage>build</clm.stage>
  </properties>

  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>Greenwich.RC2</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
      <version>5.4.18.Final</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.dom4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
      <version>6.1.5.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.0</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.objenesis</groupId>
          <artifactId>objenesis</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.0</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
          <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-vault-config</artifactId>

      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
          <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>

    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
      <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
      <version>1.66</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-consul-config</artifactId>

    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-vault-config-consul</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-core -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
      <version>5.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-config -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
      <version>5.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-web -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
      <version>5.3.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>gov.sandia.ideas</groupId>
      <artifactId>core</artifactId>
      <version>1.8.12</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
          <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>gov.sandia.ideas</groupId>
      <artifactId>ideas-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
      <version>4.1.1</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>gov.sandia.ideas</groupId>
          <artifactId>loggingClient</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
          <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
          <artifactId>bson</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-cloud-context</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
      <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
      <version>1.26</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-gateway-mvc</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.4</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>sandia.nexusoss.releases</id>
      <name>Sandia LAPS Nexus releases</name>
      <url>https://do.sandia.gov/laps3-repo/repository/maven-laps-pss-releases/</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <id>sandia.nexusoss.repo</id>
      <name>Sandia LAPS Nexus</name>
      <url>https://do.sandia.gov/laps3-repo/repository/maven-public/</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <id>sandia.nexusoss.thirdparty</id>
      <name>Sandia Corporate Nexus Repo</name>
      <url>https://do.sandia.gov/laps3-repo/repository/maven-thirdparty</url>
    </repository>

    <repository>
      <id>sandia.nexusoss.repo.ideas.public</id>
      <name>Sandia IDEAS Nexus public</name>
      <url>https://do.sandia.gov/ideas-repo/repository/ideas-public</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <id>sandia.nexusoss.repo.ideas.releases</id>
      <name>Sandia IDEAS Nexus releases</name>
      <url>https://do.sandia.gov/ideas-repo/repository/ideas-releases</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <id>sandia.nexusoss.repo.ideas.snapshot</id>
      <name>Sandia IDEAS Nexus snapshot</name>
      <url>https://do.sandia.gov/ideas-repo/repository/ideas-snapshots</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <id>sandia.nexusoss.releases</id>
      <name>Sandia LAPS Nexus releases</name>
      <url>https://do.sandia.gov/laps3-repo/repository/maven-laps-pss-releases/</url>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
      <id>sandia.nexusoss.repo</id>
      <name>Sandia LAPS Nexus</name>
      <url>https://do.sandia.gov/laps3-repo/repository/maven-public/</url>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>
  <distributionManagement>
    <repository>
      <id>sandia.nexusoss.repo</id>
      <name>Internal Release Repository</name>
      <url>https://do.sandia.gov/laps3-repo/repository/maven-laps-pss-releases/</url>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
      <id>sandia.nexusoss.repo</id>
      <name>Internal Release Repository</name>
      <url>https://do.sandia.gov/laps3-repo/repository/maven-laps-pss-snapshots/</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
  </distributionManagement>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.sonatype.clm</groupId>
        <artifactId>clm-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.16.0-01</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>index</goal>
              <goal>attach</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <arguments>-Dbuild.number=${build.number}</arguments>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>build-info</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>pl.project13.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>git-commit-id-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>get-the-git-infos</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>revision</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>initialize</phase>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <generateGitPropertiesFile>true</generateGitPropertiesFile>
          <generateGitPropertiesFilename>${project.build.outputDirectory}/git.properties</generateGitPropertiesFilename>
          <includeOnlyProperties>
            <includeOnlyProperty>^git.commit.id.(abbrev|full)$</includeOnlyProperty>
            <includeOnlyProperty>^git.commit.time$</includeOnlyProperty>
            <includeOnlyProperty>^git.branch$</includeOnlyProperty>
          </includeOnlyProperties>
          <commitIdGenerationMode>full</commitIdGenerationMode>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <release>11</release>
          <compilerArguments>
            <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
          </compilerArguments>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>copy</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
              <silent>true</silent>
              <artifactItems>
                <artifactItem>
                  <groupId>javax</groupId>
                  <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                  <version>7.0</version>
                  <type>jar</type>
                </artifactItem>
              </artifactItems>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>

    </plugins>
  </build>

  <profiles>
    <!-- LOCAL ENVIRONMENT PROFILE -->
    <profile>
      <id>local</id>
      <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
      </activation>
      <properties>
        <serverEnv>local</serverEnv>
        <loggingEnv>local</loggingEnv>
        <clm.serverUrl>https://do.sandia.gov/seis-repo/iq</clm.serverUrl>
        <clm.applicationId>${project.artifactId}</clm.applicationId>
        <clm.additionalScopes>provided, system</clm.additionalScopes>
        <clm.stage>build</clm.stage>
        <build.number>local</build.number>
      </properties>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <!-- This references the JaCoCo configuration in pluginManagement -->
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.6</version>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version> <!-- later versions can't find a new method call to test -->
            <configuration>
              <systemPropertyVariables>
                <wiremock.port>${wiremock.port}</wiremock.port>
              </systemPropertyVariables>
              <argLine>${surefireArgLine}</argLine>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>
    <!-- END LOCAL ENVIRONMENT PROFILE -->
    <!-- START CI PROFILE - TBD -->
    <profile>
      <id>ci</id>
      <properties>
        <test.config.location>${user.home}/LAPS/llc-mns-gateway-it.properties</test.config.location> <!-- TBD -->
        <build.number>ci</build.number>
      </properties>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <!-- This references the JaCoCo configuration in pluginManagement -->
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
              <argLine>${surefireArgLine}</argLine>
              <argLine>-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m</argLine>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>
    <!-- END CI PROFILE -->
    <!-- START IT PROFILE -->
    <profile>
      <id>it</id>
      <properties>
        <build.number>it</build.number>
      </properties>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.18.1</version>
            <configuration>
              <systemPropertyVariables>
                <wiremock.port>${wiremock.port}</wiremock.port>
                <spring.profiles.active>it</spring.profiles.active>
              </systemPropertyVariables>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>
    <!-- END IT PROFILE -->
  </profiles>

</project>
```

Comment: Hi Tim, I'm sorry to tell you that, but I honestly don't even know where to start. Your pom is completely messed up. First, you are using Spring Cloud Greenwich, which is not supported anymore, then for every spring dependency, you are also setting versions by hands. I think you can benefit by going through the spring guides https://spring.io/guides

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean but you can try `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose` to check from which dependencies are including which libraries. If you find duplicate ones or have a specific version to use, you can exclude others.